# How can tree level amplitudes have poles? And how can amplitudes have dimensions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering

Consider the $\phi^{3}$ theory, whose lagrangian is

$\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{2}-\frac{1}{2}m^{2}\phi^{2}-\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^{3}$

The amplitude for tree level (2->1) process is simply

$-i\lambda$

and for 2->2 process, at tree level, we'll have contributions such as

$(-i\lambda)^{2}\frac{i}{p^{2}-m^{2}}$

We see that we have a pole at $p²=m²$. My questions are

1. How can a tree level amplitude have poles? An amplitude is nothing but the inner product of some initial state with some final state, $<in|out>$. Since this we'll be interpreted as a probability, when squared, should it be between zero and 1? Shouldn't infinities appear only on loop diagrams, which would bring quantum effects? Isn't the fact that we're getting "infinity" as the answer for a tree level amplitude strange?

2-In this theory, the coupling constant is not dimensionless. As a result, the amplitude for 2->1 process $-i\lambda$ has dimenions. How can this be true? Shouldn't amplitude always be dimensionless since they will be interpreted as probabilities?

Comment: Amplitudes aren't probabilities at all... have you learned the Born rule from undergrad QM?

Comment: More specifically to this question, you should read [this](http://www.physics.indiana.edu/~dermisek/QFT_08/qft-I-10-4p.pdf).